# Is there a way to trigger the onclick of any item that is behind another item in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom-events

Basically, I am using different div to highlight sections of text.  Basically, I would like to know if the user clicked on that highlighted selection.

However. the highlighting div is behind the text, so the `onclick` method for the div does not seem to be called.  It there some trick to get around this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" >
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style="position: relative">
            <div style="width:200px;height:200px;background-color: seagreen; position: absolute; left: 40px; top: 40px; z-index: -1" onclick="alert('called?')"></div>
            <pre >
This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!
This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!
This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!
This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!
This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!
This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!
This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!
This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!
This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!
This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!
This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!
This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!
This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!
This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!
This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!
This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!
This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!
This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!
This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!
This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!
This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!
This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!
This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!
This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!This is a test!

            </pre>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you really need all of that repeated text for demo purposes?

Comment: Worth reading: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this way:

on the highlight div you could set

```
z-index:1;
opacity:0.2; /* from 0 to 1*/
filter:alpha(opacity=20); /* IE opacity fix */
```

you have to set opacity if you want to show the highlight div and in the back the text

example here: http://jsfiddle.net/steweb/Cqvve/